# Show actual image size inside Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, macos

Apple Mail offers the option to decrease or increase the size of an attached image. The options are "small", "medium" and "big".

> But how can I display the actual size in KB or MB?

*I am using Mail 8.0 in OS X Yosemite.*

Answer (score 1):

Not certain for Yosemite, but on Mavericks it's on the left of the window, level with where you choose the image size to send

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's the same under Yosemite. But if I have two or more pictures, PDFs etc, I just got the summarized size.

Comment: Yes, same for Mavericks. Only workaround would be to drop them one at a time, remove, swap to the next. A bit tedious.